# Automapper resolveusing not returning nulls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I'm working on an MVC 4 project and trying to convert a value in a KeyValue list to a nullable DateTime.  I have used the following line in the mapper (I've not included the other properties as there are a lot)

```
.ForMember(d => d.Deadline, m => m.ResolveUsing<DeadlineResolver>())
```

My resolver looks like this:

```
public class DeadlineResolver : ValueResolver<Booking, DateTime?>
{
    protected override DateTime? ResolveCore(Booking source, ResolutionResult resolutionResult)
    {
        KeyValue keyValue = source.KeyValues.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Key.KeyId == "DEADLINE");
        return (keyValue != null) ? DateTime.Parse(keyValue.Value) : (DateTime?)null; 
    }
}
```

The value of deadline which is defined as shown below is never returned as null but DateTime.MinDate instead.  I need it to be null when I'm the binding the result in a view so that I only show a value when there is a date.

```
public DateTime? Deadline { get; set; }
```

How do I make these values null without going over the values after mapping to look for min dates and set to null (temp hack I've put in place so the code runs)?

Comment: What is `KeyValue`? Is that a class you've defined?

Comment: Have you tried allowing null destination values? `Mapper.Initialize(c => c.AllowNullDestinationValues = true);`

Comment: KeyValue is a business layer object so I don't know it's full purpose as I work exclusively on the UI layer, including writing mappings from business to UI layer but I can post the details of it for clarity if you think its important @Graham?

Comment: @Mightymuke thanks for the thought, we do have AllowNullDestinationValues = true set in the configuration file.

Comment: What version AutoMapper are you using?

Comment: @Mightymuke I'm using version 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Using LinqPad and AutoMapper 2.2.1 the following gives me a valid date when `KeyValue` has a date, and a `null` `DateTime` when `KeyValue` is `null`. (Note there are minor changes to the resolver to simplify it as the class definitions weren't provided).

```cs
void Main()
{
    AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Booking, dest>()
        .ForMember(d => d.Deadline, m => m.ResolveUsing<DeadlineResolver>());
    AutoMapper.Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

    // Gives a valid DateTime
    var booking = new Booking { KeyValue = "2013-01-01" };
    booking.Dump();
    var rc = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Booking, dest>(booking);
    rc.Dump();

    // Gives a null DateTime
    booking = new Booking { KeyValue = null };
    booking.Dump();
    rc = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Booking, dest>(booking);
    rc.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Booking
{
    public string KeyValue { get; set; }
}

public class dest
{
    public DateTime? Deadline { get; set; }
}

public class DeadlineResolver : AutoMapper.ValueResolver<Booking, DateTime?>
{
    protected override DateTime? ResolveCore(Booking source)
    {
        return (source.KeyValue != null)
            ? DateTime.Parse(source.KeyValue)
            : (DateTime?)null; 
    }
}
```

Is this the functionality you were after? If so, then the issue could be with an older version of AutoMapper, or an unexpected `KeyValue` value.

Comment: Thanks @Mightymuke, I didn't provide the class definitions as I was wary of including too much irrelevant code, your simplification looks reasonable to me.  I'm using verion 2.0 of automapper, do you think that could be the problem?

Comment: Could be. I do know there have been recent fixes related to mapping nulls for nullable fields, but can't find the specific issue that might relate to this. For example: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/257

Comment: Thanks for all your help with this @Mightymuke, I really appreciate the time you've spent.  I think I'm going to leave my hack in place for now as it's too late in the cycle to upgrade automapper for this project.  I'll definitely make sure I'm using the latest version next time though.